# Groovy Thread Safety

Tags: multithreading, groovy

I am using groovy scripting execution in multi threaded mode.
Script themselves are thread safe.

Its like below:
//Startup Code. Single threaded

```
Class<?> scriptClass = getScriptClass(fileName); //utility to get script class from file name
Method method = getMethods(scriptClass); //Utility to get a specific Method
storeMethod(method); //Store method globally.
Object scriptInstance = scriptClass.newInstance();
storeScriptInstance(scriptInstance); //Store script Instance
```

Multiple threads execute following code: (without any synchronization.)

```
ScriptInstance scriptInstance = getScriptInstance(); //Utility to get scriptInstance stored in init
Method method = getMethod(); //Utility for getting method stored in init step
Object obj[] = new Object[] { context }; //context variable available per thread.
method.invoke(scriptInstance,obj);
```

script consists of just one function which is totally thread safe (function is reentrant and modifies context variable.)

This works in my unit testing with multiple threads but couldn't find any material to support this claim. 
Question => Is it safe under multiple thread execution? More generically, sharing of same script instances across threads to execute scripts functions which themselves are thread safe is safe? Script instances shouldn't have global variables in execution.
Context is an argument to script and not global variable.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the actual function I cannot tell if this is supposed to be threadsafe or not. Since you say that the function modifies the context variable I conclude that you mutate global state. In that case it is not threadsafe without synchronization of some kind. If my assumption is wrong and no global state is mutated, then executing a method by reflection is surely not the problem

Comment: Context is passed via argument to script and not global. Can I conclude its thread safe? Script themselves are thread safe as they are reentrant in nature.

Comment: as much as you have shown should be. But I would not build on Scripts themselves are being thread safe. A Script instance from Groovy for example might be save, the Binding it uses by default is not. If your are really not sharing mutable global state, there is no problem though

Comment: Thanks blackdrag I don't use binding. The script is like below: def fun(Context ctx) { ctx.setX(...);ctx.setY(...); return ctx;}. Based on your answer I conclude its thread safe. Thanks for answering.

Comment: as I said, as long as you don't mutate global state, you are fine. But ctx.setX implies mutation. And since context comes from outside, it might be global. So this is potentially not thread safe. As long as you don't create a new context instance for each thread I see here a potential thread issue

Comment: ctx is created different inside each thread. Its per message actually. void handleMsg(Msg msg) {Ctx  ctx = new Ctx(msg);}. I think its thread safe. Main intention of this question I was not sure how scriptinstance works. It doesn't have any global variables of its own though. Rest I can handle. Thanks once again for taking time to answer.

Comment: a mistake in my comment... context is fine as long as it is not shared or created from shared data without synchronization. So if you say context is done per message (aka method call), then it is fine, as long as the data you create it from is fine. But I take your comments as that is fine, so I guess it is relatively safe